# Проблемы с поиском плагинов в Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android-studio, плагин

Пытаюсь попробовать флаттер. Студия 3.2. Захожу в file-settings-plugins-'browse repositories' и вижу там единственный плагин - kotlin 1.2.60. Поиск и рефреш не дают ничего. Пробую делать то же через студию 3.1 - все отрабатывает корректно - полный список плагинов и флаттер ищется. В итоге я конечно могу остаться на 3.1, но так как для всехх проектов я ушел на 3.2 - не хочется даунгрейдиться только для флаттера или держать две студии. Может эта штука чем то лечится?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже нужно было просто подождать.

По умолчанию репозиторий обзывается

url?{version num} где version num это версия сборки студии/идеи, что-то вроде 171.43432...

Соответственно при выходе свежего обновления не все плагины успевают перекочевать в новую директорию в репозитории, подозреваю, что они должны пройти тесты и так далее. Проверил сегодня - список обновился и флаттер на месте